# How can I create a function to convert the string "ABCD" to an array like: ["A", "AB", "ABC", "ABCD"] in Javascript?

Tags: javascript, arrays, string, algorithm, loops

How can I create a function to convert the string "ABCD" to an array like: ["A", "AB", "ABC", "ABCD"] in Javascript ?

---

(I don't know how to exactly describe this process in English so I just put the question in the title, so, would be great if there was a special term for it to be known.. :))

Comment: The term is "generate (non-empty) prefixes of the string". You can do using a loop and the string `.slice()` method.

Comment: [`for`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for) and [`string::substring`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/substring) might help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

this way...?

```js
console.log( foo('ABCD') );

function foo(str)
  {
  let res = [], s='';
  for (let c of str) res.push( s+=c );
  return res;
  }
```

Or ?

```js
const foo = str => Array.from(str,(_,i) => str.slice(0,i+1));
 
console.log( foo('ABCD') )
```

Comment: Better use `i+1` than `++i`

Answer (score 1):

```
const s = 'ABCD'

function f(s) {
    return s // = 'ABCD'
        // make array of length s.length
        .split('') // = ['A','B','C','D']
        // map it to slices of length (i+1)
        .map(
            (
                e,// = 'A','B','C','D'
                i, // = 0,1,2,3
            ) => s.slice(0, i + 1)
        ) // = what you said
}

console.log(f(s))
```

Answer (score 1):

One way to do it, without any fancy stuff, just a basic `for` loop:

```js
    var str = 'ABCD'
    var new_str = '';
    var arr_string = new Array();
    
    for (var i = 0; i < str.length; i++) {
        new_str += str.charAt(i);
        arr_string[i] = new_str
    }
    
    console.log(arr_string);
```

Answer (score 0):

A more readable approach:

```
const getProgressiveArray = (string) => {
  let concat = '';
  const progressiveArray = [];

  for (let character of string) {
    concat += character;
    progressiveArray.push(concat);
  }

  return progressiveArray;
};
```

Remember, a string is iterable, making issues like this more straightforward. Pairing this fact with the `for...of` loop, can result in a concise and readable solution.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

```js
    const str = 'ABCD'

     function convertString(str) {
     var str = str.split('')  //['A','B','C','D']

    .map((items, index ) => str.slice(0, index + 1)) //[ 'A', 'AB', 'ABC', 'ABCD' ]
        return str 
    }

    console.log(convertString(str))
```